# Facing architectural issue when fetching data from another service

Tags: c#, webapi

We are having one internet facing web api which is getting data from another intranet service. Problem is intranet web service is having windows authentication where as web api is having anonymous authentication. So while fetching data from web service getting 501 error. We can not implement windows authentication in Web Api as it is internet facing. Could anyone please suggest what architectural changes need to implement.

[Architecture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB56e.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proper implementation of "windows" authentication in web api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545659/proper-implementation-of-windows-authentication-in-web-api)

Comment: Your web api in the DMZ IS a user (the application pool user) so it should be able to connect to the internal web api if the user has the proper permissions. Change the application pool user to one with the proper permissions and you should be fine